# How to access strings in JSON string array in Angular 2+?

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I am new to Angular and Coding.

I currently have this line of code that is filtering my brands in my json. The piece of code that is `m.Properties`. Basically what the code below does is its looking at the brands and filtering the brands where the properties of the brand are the same as the strings in the `filteredProperties` array.

```
    for (var i = this.filteredProperties.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this.filteredProperties[i] == property) {
            this.visibleBrands = this.brands.filter(m => m.Properties == this.filteredProperties.find(y => y === m.Properties));
        }
    }
```

However right now my JSON looks like this, note it is hard coded into my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Brands } from '../models/brand.model';

@Injectable() 
export class BrandService {


    getBrands(): Brands[] {
        return [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Title": "Alternative Investments",
                "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin ornare lectus, quis gravida tortor venenatis nec.",
                "ImageUrl": "C:/Users/xy57418/Pictures/Anguar Rewrite/PlaceHolder BrandLogos.png",
                "FundsUrl": "www.google.com",
                "OurPeopleUrl": "www.google.com",
                "WhyInvestUrl": "www.google.com",
                "MoreInfoUrl": "www.google.com",
                "Properties": ["institutional"],

            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Customised Solutions",
                "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin ornare lectus, quis gravida tortor venenatis nec. ",
                "ImageUrl": "C:/Users/xy57418/Pictures/Anguar Rewrite/PlaceHolder BrandLogos.png",
                "FundsUrl": "www.google.com",
                "OurPeopleUrl": "www.google.com",
                "WhyInvestUrl": "www.google.com",
                "MoreInfoUrl": "www.google.com",
                "Properties":["personal"],

            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Title": "Future Growth",
                "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin ornare lectus, quis gravida tortor venenatis nec. ",
                "ImageUrl": "C:/Users/xy57418/Pictures/Anguar Rewrite/PlaceHolder BrandLogos.png",
                "FundsUrl": "www.google.com",
                "OurPeopleUrl": "www.google.com",
                "WhyInvestUrl": "www.google.com",
                "MoreInfoUrl": "www.google.com",
                "Properties": ["institutional"],

            },
            {
                "Id": 4,
                "Title": "Global Emerging Markets",
                "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin ornare lectus, quis gravida tortor venenatis nec. ",
                "ImageUrl": "C:/Users/xy57418/Pictures/Anguar Rewrite/PlaceHolder BrandLogos.png",
                "FundsUrl": "www.google.com",
                "OurPeopleUrl": "www.google.com",
                "WhyInvestUrl": "www.google.com",
                "MoreInfoUrl": "www.google.com",
                "Properties": ["institutional", "personal"],

            },
        ]
    }
}
```

My Model looks like this:

```
export class Brands {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    ImageUrl: string;
    FundsUrl: string;
    OurPeopleUrl: string;
    WhyInvestUrl: string;
    MoreInfoUrl: string;
    Properties: string[];
}
```

So as you can see the problem that occurs is that it returns undefined when I select `m.Properties`. I am using an input checkbox to filter. I am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: Here is my input box code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Personal" value="Personal" [(ngModel)]="Personal" (change)="checkValue(Personal, property='personal')"/> Personal<br />
```

So what happens is when the input box is clicked, the property is added to the array `filteredProperties`. These are the properties that are currently being looked for in the JSON properties.

EDIT 2:

So I was able to use part of @trichetriche answer and use `indexOf` to get a result.

My Code:

```
this.visibleBrands = this.brands.filter(item => item.Properties.some(property => this.filteredProperties.indexOf(property) > -1));
```

Comment: Please provide either your full code or a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io.

Comment: Please provide more details on 'm' and how data arrives, furthermore is that your complete json file which you just posted?

Comment: No it sits in an angular service. I will edit in my full service.

Comment: Where is that you are retrieving the json? and what is the output when you do console.log(m) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you're trying to check if at least one of the `m.properties` is in your `brand.properties`.

If this is the case, here is how you do it :

```js
const data = [{
  "Id": 4,
  "Title": "Global Emerging Markets",
  "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin ornare lectus, quis gravida tortor venenatis nec. ",
  "IUrl": "www.google.com",
  "FUrl": "www.google.com",
  "OUrl": "www.google.com",
  "WUrl": "www.google.com",
  "MUrl": "www.google.com",
  "Properties": ["institutional", "personal"],
}];

const validProperties = ['personal', 'financial'];
const invalidProperties = ['marital', 'governmental'];

console.log(data.filter(item => item.Properties.some(property => validProperties.indexOf(property) !== -1)));
console.log(data.filter(item => item.Properties.some(property => invalidProperties.indexOf(property) !== -1)));
```

You have to "compare" two arrays : this means that one array has to have at least one of its elements matching the other array.

To do that, you're going to use `filter` first : it will remove any items not matching the condition.

Next, you will have to check every item of your `Properties` array, and check if this item is included in the second array.

This is done with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which can be summed up like this

> Iterate over every element of the array ; if one item is matching the condition, stop the iteration and return true.

The condition is `array.includes`, which is self explanatory I guess.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I am unable to implement it due to the fact that `includes` is not in es6 but is in es2016. So I will get back to trying out your solution. But it seems promising.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot, check EDIT 2.

Comment: I have updated my answer with `indexOf`, because you are using the wrong condition.

Comment: @DanielBailey also, are you filtering the values in your `checkValue` function ? If not, your model won't be updated and you won't see a thing !

Comment: I updated my code with a similar condition and then saw yours, pretty much the same thing and it works. Thanks so much for the help, will update your answer as correct.

Comment: Basically the same yes. Good luck wth your project !

Answer (score 0):

What you are returning in  **getBrands(): Brands[]** is an array of objects, so you have to traverse through each item ie `m[0].Properties, m[1].Properties` and so on. So what you should be doing is accessing `m[i].Properties` in a loop. Had it been a single object ie {} without [{}] , m.Properties would have worked. I hope I'm clear on this.